# multicolor gradient feature in bar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to display 3 color gradient bar graph as below. Presently I am able to display 2 color gradient but finding difficulty with 3 colors.

I saw there are some other questions for the same topic, do we have added this feature in the present version, or any way I can customize the add the feature?

[image]